# Is there a way to "un-render" a bundle of JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

Currently, we are bundling Bootstrap files like this:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/Site.css"));
    }
}
```

And we are applying these bundles to our HTML files using this command:

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")`

However, we are hoping to move away from using Bootstrap incrementally as we have onboarded a UX/UI expert who doesn't want to use Bootstrap.

**Is there any way to undo the @Scripts.Render command or to apply Bootstrap to only a specific portion of a view? Is the @Scripts.Render command inherited by all child partial views?**

Comment: Short answer is no. And partials are just a server side concept - its all merged and sent to the browser as one html document. Since bundling minifies and caches the files, the performance hit is minimal, but you could always create a 2nd layout file without the bootstrap bundle and then as you modify the view, change the associated layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Stephen Muecke commented is absolutely correct. I would like to add few more.

> Is there any way to undo the @Scripts.Render command or to apply
>   Bootstrap to only a specific portion of a view?

You cannot undo the rendered scripts.
You cannot limit it to a specific portion of a view. And the rendered scripts will be applied to all partials.

> Is the @Scripts.Render command inherited by all child partial views?

Yes.

This is what you can do.

1. Create a different partial for non Bootstrap pages.
2. Use the same partial and conditionally load this bundle.

We did this for conditional loading. We added a flag in ViewBag.

```
ViewBag.isBootStrapRequired = true;
```

In the layout page, we loaded the bundle like this.

```
if(ViewBag.isBootStrapRequired) {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
}
```